# Dynamic properties for a typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I wanted to make an interface with dynamic properties, for example with this object:

```
test: testInterface [];

this.test = [
  {
    name: {
      text: 'something',
      anotherThing: 'something'
    }
  },
  {
    foo: {
      text: 'something',
      anotherThing: 'something'
    }
  },
  {
    whatever: {
      text: 'something',
      anotherThing: 'something'
    }
  },
];
```

text, foo and whatever (could be any name and the array could have any number of items)

I tried something like this:

```
export interface testInterface {
  [propName: string]: testSubInterface;
}

interface testSubInterface {
  text: string;
  anotherThing: string;
}
```

But It doesn't works for me, The final idea is to change the data like this:

```
this.testInterface.foo.text = "another text for example";
```

any idea?

Comment: It works perfectly, isn't it? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDqgZxgEkU0tc4BvAKDjgG0woIwA5TAW2AC44ioyAOYBdPoRgBlAK4AjUqgw5gAbhoBfGjWSKKeCTPlkllWvVQgYfAcLX1MSCDAAWaACrPh1mIKRC1mjQAJsDYADaYUHjYEEhEcCDiwEQK5MpqNCAAdOgQEFkW8AC8cABEDk6uUPig8LnVoFxgYcClKkA

Comment: "It doesn't work for me" isn't really descriptive enough; please provide a [mre] that shows exactly what the problem.  Is the issue that you are using an array instead of a single object?  If so, then does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO8glN) meet your needs?  If not, can you articulate why you want an array instead?

Comment: Yes I mixed many concepts. The main thing is that I wanted to do with and array because I had to iterate it in the template, but I found a solution for this with *ngFor="let item of testInterface | keyvalue". Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface is correct but your object is declared wrongly.

You `test` should be declared as an object, not an array.

```
const test: testInterface = {
  name: {
    text: "something",
    anotherThing: "something"
  },
  foo: {
    text: "something",
    anotherThing: "something"
  },
  whatever: {
    text: "something",
    anotherThing: "something"
  }
};

this.testInterface.foo.text = "another text for example";
```

Comment: Oh thats right I mixed some concepts. Thanks you very much